# Is there a way to cycle through elements in an array using the onClick function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data.

```js
const quotes = [             
  {"author": "Marilyn Monroe",
   "quote" : "I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best." },
  {"author" : "Oscar Wilde",
  "quote" :  "Be yourself, everyone else is already taken."}
]
```

I want to render an individual object to a div. I then want to cycle through the objects in the array when i click on the button

This is what I have tried so far :

```
class ‘MyComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
}
sayHello() {
  return quotes[(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(quotes.length)))];
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="body">
    <div className="quote">
  <p>“ {this.sayHello.quote} “</p>  
    </div>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.sayHello.quotes.quote}>New Quote</button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

};

function Create(props){
return (

{this.sayHello.author}

)
};

I want to be able to get a new object rendered to the div when I click the button.
I'm extremely new to react. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a functional component to simplify this. Then use the useState hook to keep track of which quote you are showing. Then randomly assign a quote to the state on button click using a callback function. Here is an example of this.

```
import React from "react"

const quotes = [{
  author: "Marilyn Monroe",
  quote: "I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best." 
  }, {
  author: "Oscar Wilde",
  quote: "Be yourself, everyone else is already taken."
  }];

export const MyComponent = (props) =>{
const [quoteIndex, setQuoteIndex] = React.useState(0);
const setNewQuote = () => {
  setQuoteIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length));
}

  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div className="quote">
        <p>“ {quotes[quoteIndex]} “</p>  
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={setNewQuote}>New Quote</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with your code, the biggest being that you're not actually *calling* your `sayHello` method.

A working example of your code could look like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      quote: ""
    };
  }
  sayHello() {
    this.setState({
      quote: quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)].quote
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <div className="quote">
          <p>“{this.state.quote}“</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.sayHello()}>
          New Quote
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-lumiere-2wi29?file=/src/App.js) if you want to play around with it.